# Apollo server v2/v3 gzip compression

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

Anyone know the best future proof practice / pattern for enabling gzip compression in apollo v2, given that the road map for v3 details that all apollo-server- are going to be deprecated in favour of the in house http transport layer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable gzip at GraphQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187470/how-to-enable-gzip-at-graphql-server)

Comment: No, that does not provide a way to enable gzip on an Apollo gql server. The answer below does.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you'll have to use something like NGINX https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/compression/

Answer (score 0):

Use `apollo-server-express`

- v2: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/migration-two-dot/#apollo-server-2-new-pattern
- v3: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/middleware/#apollo-server-express

with `express/compression`: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/compression.html